# On the fly projection of raster images no longer works in QGIS 3.6.1

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, coordinates, county

For years I have created QGIS projects from Shapefiles using ESRI County Coordinate prj files. I have always been able to add aerial imagery from an ESRI ARCGIS Online server or local server and the imagery reprojects quite well. However, with the newest QGIS release, version 3.6.1 NOOSA, aerial imagery reprojects into lat, long, even if the  source projection of that imagery is UTM.

Other than uninstalling version 3.6.1 and   going back to an older version of QGIS, is there an elegant, simple and efficient way to handle this problem?

Comment: Just change your map CRS, on-the-fly reprojection is now the default in QGIS 3x.

Comment: Been there, done that. Doesn't work. When you set the project crs to the correct county coordinate system then add a raster image with a native UTM crs, the raster reprojects to lat long. With previous versions you didn't  have to set the project crs and raster images reprojected properly. Thanks for trying.

Comment: On mac Qgis 3.4.11 I also have this problem a Geotff in 3857 for london plots in the sea off the coast of Africa

Answer (score 1):

I started noticing the same problem at 3.20.3.  Funny thing, though... the problem wasn't there a few hours earlier.

After a lot of research, I found that the problem was in the User Profile.  Somehow it had become corrupt (my term), and replacing it with a new default profile solved the problem (instructions on how to replace the User Profile can be found in the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#working-with-user-profiles) or elsewhere here in SE GIS).

Unfortunately, replacing the User Profile with a new default is a pretty drastic measure, because it removes all personal settings and customizations.  So prior to doing the replacement I saved my original profile folder (the "corrupt" version) under a different name. Then I started QGIS and created a new default profile.  I then quit QGIS and deleted the new profile.  *Then* I renamed the original "corrupt" profile folder back to "default" and restarted QGIS.  Go figure, but the "raster-projection" problem *went away(!)*  I dunno why it works just fine now, but I include my convoluted profile renaming/deleting steps in case others find it useful!